# How do I cut and paste transpose data multiple times

Tags: excel, transpose, office-2010

I have a spreadsheet where I need to copy every 18 rows from sheet 1 and transpose paste into sheet 2. I have to do this over 100 times. Any options on how to automate this process?

Comment: Use the `Transpose` function

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D4:H4").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B6").Value)
```